Which is primarily responsible for centering a wheel in seemingly over-constrained wheel centering?
It would be pointless to install the best balanced wheel in the world if the wheel is not centered on the hub.
I'm confused by there being two systems for centering each wheel: the mounting bolts and the centering ring.
How does this work, at the tens of micrometers range? Is the centering ring responsible for getting a wheel exactly centered, and there is (otherwise imperceptible) play in the mounting bolts and lug nuts?


It depends on the kind of nut used.
Acorn nuts, in particular, will not center a wheel. Centering is done through the center bolt, which must match that on the wheel.
